# Icon won't appear in CKEditor plug-in

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a plug-in that I made for CKEditor.  It works perfectly.  I needed another one very similar to it, so I copied/pasted/renamed everything.  Then I changed the icon out to something else... same dimensions (16x16), etc.  I've gone through it several times to be sure everything is named properly... casing, etc.

But after clearing my cache and reloading the page, the new icon never appears.  I've tried several icons, including just re-using the other plug-in's exactly.  It never appears.  Not even a "blank" appears (which happened during development of the last one).

The docs are pretty worthless in that respect, so I don't know what to do.  It seems like this should be a simple fix.  I hope it is.  Here's the plugin.js:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('attachfile',{
    icons:'attachfile',
    init:function(editor){
        editor.addCommand('attachfile',new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('attachfileDialog'));
    editor.ui.addButton('attachfile',{
        label:'Attach File',
        command:'attachFile',
        toolbar:'insert'
    });
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('attachfileDialog',this.path + 'dialogs/attachfile.js');
}
});
```

[image: This is the directory structure]
Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
CKEDITOR.timestamp='SOMEVALUE';
```

This is what CKEDITOR uses to control caching of files, so every time you change something you need to give this a new timestamp. If you dont, it will continue to make your browser use cached files.

The problem you might have is that CKEDITOR still loads its old files before it reads your timestamp value. So you must set this before CKEDITOR loads its files. You can try to sett it as the first thing to happen after the ckeditor.js is included. Setting it in the config file, can in some cases be to late, because at that time, many files are already loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/g_adminlib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" >
                CKEDITOR.timestamp = 'something_random'; 
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean in the config.js file?

Comment: Tried that... no luck. I tried putting it above the CKEDITOR.editorConfig area, then changed it to config.timestamp and put it inside it.  Neither made a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: That wasn't it either, but I figured it out because you got me to looking at the config.js and realized I had left something out!   Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that when you set this in config.js, it has already loded its files, so it is using the old config.js... make sence ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it was something simple.  I had failed to enter the plug-in name into the "extraPlugins" line in the config.js.